# How to get the span text content within template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor

I have a problem using jQuery to retrieve Span element from within the template. Here is my code:

```
Template.item.events({
'click .remove':function(event,tpl){
        Meteor.call('tasks.remove',this._id);
        var docEmail=tpl.find('#DocName');
        alert(docEmail.text());
        Meteor.call('doc.removeAuthorization', docEmail, this._id);

    },});
```

My definition of the template:

```
<template name="item">
 <li class="{{#if ischecked}}mychecked{{/if}}">
   <input type="checkbox" checked="{{ischecked}}" class="check-box"/>
   <strong><span name="DocEmail" id="DocName">{{content}}></span></strong>
   <span> {{CreatTime}}</span>
   <button class="remove">&times;</button>      

 </li></template>
```

Here is how the template is placed in the body:

```
<ul>
{{#each tasks}}
    <li>{{> item}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

I have read many posts on how to use jquery or jscript to get span text. I think I have tried all of them. All gave me similar error:

**body.js:162 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null**

I also tried using  and tpl.find(".DocName"). Got the same type of error.

Also tried tpl.$(). Same error.

Is this because the span element did not exist when the template.find() function was called?

But I have seen people using similar code to get DOM element(other than span text) with success.

I thought my tasks.remove might have remove the text before the jQuery was called. So I changed the order of calling two Meteor.call s. It is like this:

```
Template.item.events({
'click .remove':function(event,tpl){
        Meteor.call('tasks.remove',this._id);
        var docEmail=tpl.find('#DocName');
        alert(docEmail.value);
        Meteor.call('doc.removeAuthorization', docEmail, this._id);

    },});
```

Now I get undefined alert.
If I use docEmail.val() or docEmail.text(), I get "docEmail.val() is not a function.".

Hope you guys can shed some light on it!
Thank you!

Comment: Did u placed this inside the jquery ready event?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN   Thank you for mentioning this.  No I did not put the code inside jquery ready event. I am new to jQuery. Did not even hear about jQuery ready event before. I tried and it worked!   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think it's useful:

```
$( "span" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: This is helpful!  Now I know that the span element are in an array form. And it is nice to know how to use the .each() function. But I want to get text from a specific span that is responding to the button click. Using the .ready() event seems to be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this,

```
var docEmail=tpl.find('#DocName').value;
```

without "()"

Comment: I tried this before I posted the question. Also tried .val() and .text(). None was working. I think I got the answer. The answer is to use .ready().  Thank you for answering!